# RichTextBox SpellChecker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rtf, spell-checking

i've added a reference to the Presentation framework to enable spellchecking support on the RichTextBox control in my WinForms application (.NET 4.0). I've tried

```
Windows.Controls.SpellCheck.SetIsEnabled(rtf)
```

and

```
Windows.Controls.SpellCheck.SetIsEnabled(DirectCast(rtf, Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase), True)
```

But in both cases VS complains that the RTB is not a descendant of the TextBoxBase class, although the MSDN docs claim it does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure how you have added a reference to the Presentation framework, but bear in mind that the link you are posting refer to WPF code and thus the best way to get this functionality is creating a WPF application (if you do that, you would see that both RichTextBox and TextBox have SpellCheck as a Property).

Comment: ah I see so I can use ElementHost then

Comment: Never used that (neither particular fan of WPF). Although, in general, is always better to not mix-up things; if you are interested in various WPF functionalies, perhaps you should consider the option to create a WPF application. Or even you might add some WPF parts to your project (or create a dll with the control(s) you want and reference them from your project). Link you might find interesting: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/825a22fd-c9f0-46b5-b99f-fd61daf676b5/wpf-dll-in-a-winforms-application

Comment: One of the defining features of the .NET is precisely the compatility between the different languages forming it. One thing is taking advantage from the general .NET compatiblity rules (thoroughly tested and validated) and adding two different languages to your project; and a different thing is relying on a specific, relatively-new feature (ElementHost). As said, never tried and not sure about its reliability but, a priori, I would use the first options: either relying completely on WPF or combining winforms and WPF parts.